# Why the recycler view didn't come in activity page when I type recycler view

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

It doesn't import 
androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView 
to main activity when i type recyclerview in main activity . Its still shows me as 
import... 
like that . I need to use linear layout as well to continue my coding . But its dent working . why?

Comment: So what do you want, RecyclerView or LinearLayout.

Comment: You probably forgot the `LinearLayoutManager`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to add `RecyclerView` to dependencies
2. You don't need a `LinearLayout`. `RecyclerView` will set it for you when you add `viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)`.

You can learn more about `RecyclerView` in this tutorial created by Coding in Flow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARpn-1FPNE4&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuDihTpkRs6SpZhqgBqPU118

Check this docs out: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

- As a new member, you are expected to post your code and make your problems clear. You don't just ask why it doesn't work without showing the code. We cannot help you when you don't post any code or when you make us code something for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should add recycler view dependencies in your `build.gradle` file

In case you still use non-androidX, you should add this line in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

Or if you already use androidX, you should add this line in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0"
}
```